# How to get max X and Max Y points in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-animation

Im using

```
RectF(float left, float top, float right, float bottom)
```

to create a rectangle. For some the max x value and max y value going out of Screen. But the same values lies inside the screen for some big screens. So is there anyway to check what is the max value for the current Screen so that i can use the cordinates within the screen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can fetch width and height of screen, by following:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

here width and height are max points in x and y direction.

Comment: Thank U jitendra. But display.getSize(size); dint worked for me. So i used display.getHeight(); and display.getWidth();

Comment: I second Vins comment... 04-10 13:37:59.957: E/AndroidRuntime(3222): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.view.Display.getSize

   ----- Worked fine on Android 4.0.4 (ICS) but wouldn't on 2.3.7 (cyanogen mod) ... going to use getHeight() and its buddy (assuming it works on ICS)

Comment: @jeet could you elaborate on `display.getSize(size);`  , please?